# Windows 11 bootable media fails with NFTS_FILE_SYSTEM BSOD

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bsod

I'm building a brand new PC. I've downloaded and run the [official program](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) to create a bootable USB key.

After correctly setting up the boot media first in UEFI, the PC boots for a few seconds, and then I get a Windows bluescreen: "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We'll restart it for you". The stop code is `NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM`.

Does that mean that there is something wrong with the USB key's filesystem, or with one of the PC's disks? The disks are brand new and obviously not formatted in NTFS yet.

I can't seem to access any disk checking or formatting utility after booting.

Comment: Try another USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by formatting the key as NTFS, then recreating the bootable media on it.

I expected the media creation tool to do this for me, but it turns out that it doesn't.